# Get-PNP**** cmdlets not working even after installing PnP.Powerhsell latest verision

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I have installed PowerShell 7 and installed module PnP.PowerShell, when i tab the commands, it is working [Get-Help of the cmdlet (Get-PnPGroupMember) provides the required output], but when i run the script getting following error not sure.

Failed;https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite;The '**Get-PnPGroupMember**' command was found in the module 'PnP.PowerShell'

[image]

Not sure, where and what i am missing ?

Comment: _PowerShell 7_ and _Windows PowerShell_ are different products! They do not share installed modules…

Comment: Just to mention i checked on both, @JosefZ found the RCA, will mention in answer

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module and re-installation PnP.PowerShell solved the issue, may the issue is because of having old verision of SharePoint online cmdlets caused the issue.